# how to filter post data from typescript in my web api

Tags: typescript

im trying to filter the data of a post from my typescript. But i dont know how i can access the data in my web api to work with it.

My Typescript filter Method:
Here im trying to post my data to my web api

```html
sendToFilter(){
    let filterObject = {
      vorname: this.vornameFilter,
    }
    this.filterService.sendFilterToServer(filterObject).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    console.log(filterObject);
  }
```

My post Service:

```html
sendFilterToServer(data:any): Observable<ServerModel[]>{
    return this.http.post<ServerModel[]>(this.filterAdress, data);

  }
```

In my WebApi:
Here i dont know how i can access the sended filterObject to compare the string "vorname" with my database for example.

```html
[HttpPost("filter/")]
        public IActionResult Filter([FromBody] Personen user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            Console.Write(user);

            return null;
        }
```

thx in Advance

Comment: How is this a typescript question, Are you not asking how to filter data in your backend?
If not using typescript is the data being filtered?

Comment: data comes from typescript and filtered in backend

Comment: what is the exact problem? where exactly is it failing? your question is a bit too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a solution by myself.

```html
[HttpPost("filter/")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Filter([FromBody] Filter user)
        {


            return Ok(await _context
                .Personens
                //Obere Felder (nicht erweitert)
                .Where(p => p.Vorname.ToLower().Contains(user.vorname))
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    personId = p.PersonId,
                    vorname = p.Vorname,
                }).ToListAsync());

        }
```

Through the parameter /filter you can access the object filterObject from the frontend.